# how would i replace one string values with another without breaking it

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bbc-microbit

I've been trying to learn the microbit and Raspberry Pi but I can't figure out how to increase the amount of things that are measured by it,

```
import time
import serial
from datetime import datetime
from csv import writer
import http.server

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)

while True:
    x=ser.readline()
    if x:
        dt = datetime.now()
        datestamp = str(dt)[:16]
        temp, light = x.decode().split(':')
        newData = [datestamp,temp,light]
        print(newData)
        with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_object:
            writer_object = writer(f_object)
            writer_object.writerow(newData)
```

I tried replacing

```
temp, light = x.decode().split(':')          
newData = [datestamp,temp,light]
```

with longer and other values, however nothing works, I was expecting more outputs to be produced that just weren't however no error was given out.

Link to original code I am basing my work on:
https://github.com/blogmywiki/microbit-pi-data

This is how I have modified that example code on micro:bit to send more data:
[image: microbit code example]

no errors outputted.

when i next have access to pi and whatnot ill add the code from the pi

Comment: It is impossible for us to know what isn't working with what you have shown. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. This means showing an example of the blocks on the micro:bit and the python code on the Raspberry Pi. Also include any error messages you are getting when you run your code.

Comment: @ukBaz 
im receiving no errors when running the program 
https://ibb.co/kXPcLkn

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to change? It sounds like you want to get additonal data fields from the serial port and then write them to the csv, but its not entirely clear what you meant by "longer and other values"

Answer (score 1):

In the example you linked, the two values are being joined with a `:` and written in a single operation. The code then reads this line and splits it by the `:` to get the two values.

In *your* microbit code, you send each value separately, with no `:`, so not surprisingly, the line in the Python code which splits the received data, fails, because there is no delimiter.

So, you either need to change the microbit code to join the values with the colon, again, or change the Python code to parse the data in the new format. Which you choose to do is up to you.